# window.parent.postMessage to @Listener

Tags: stenciljs

We have a requirement that we load a separate page as a modal (yay, right?)

The embedded page uses `window.parent.postMessage(messageString, '*')` to signal actions have been completed.

I want to use stenciljs's `@Listener`

I have a working modal with an iframe to the other page, using the old school `window.addEventListener('message', myMessageHandlingDelegate)`.

however, I really would like to use the `@Listener` attribute/decorator to handle the result of the posted message. I tried `@Listener('message')` but the code was not added....

is there away to get a stenciljs listener to catch messages posted from child Iframes?

Comment: Hi Nathan. Did you ever get this to work? I am struggling with the exact same issue right now and can't seem to get stenciljs to listen to the message event emitted inside an iframe.

Comment: I ended up getting it working. I'll post code in new answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Listen` decorator is used to add listener to JavaScript custom events (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) or to events emitted by a Stencil child component. That means that you can't use Message API (using `window.postMessage` or listening to the message event) with that decorator. You can still use the `addEventListener` to the message event like you indicated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code in the stenciljs custom component to get this working:

```
@Listen('message', { target: 'window' })
handleMessage(ec) {
  console.log("Event from iFrame triggered");
}
```